# Excel Macro to delete a row if cell in Column A equals cell in Column B

Tags: vba, excel

Need some help here. Nothing that I've searched for seems to fit my situation. I have a large data set where Column A and Column B have some duplicates. To clarify, it is a personnel data set with Column A being employees and column B being spouses of those employees. However, some employees are married to each other, so I would like to delete the second instance on the list where both employees are married to each other. A sample of my data is this:

```
Column A  
Kim  
Dave  
Jim  
Mary  
Mike
```

---

```
Column B  
Mike  
Angela  
Susan  
Bob  
Kim
```

In this case, Mike is married to Kim, which is depicted in both rows 1 and 5. I want to delete row 5. It is a rather large dataset, so doing it manually would take hours with a probability of human error. Thanks!\

Edited to include my code:

```
Sub DeleteDuplicates()

Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Declare variables
Dim var As Variant, iSheet As Integer, iRow As Long, iRowL As Long, bln As Boolean

   'Set up the count as the number of filled rows in the first column of Sheet1.
   iRowL = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row

   'Cycle through all the cells in that column:
   For iRow = 2 To iRowL
      'For every cell that is not empty, search through the first column in each worksheet in the
      'workbook for a value that matches that cell value.

      If Not IsEmpty(Cells(iRow, 2)) Then
         For iSheet = ActiveSheet.Index + 1 To Worksheets.Count
            bln = False
            var = Application.Match(Cells(iRow, 2).Value, ActiveSheet.Columns(9), 0)

            'If you find a matching value, clear the cell contents and exit the loop;
            'otherwise, continue searching until you reach the end of the workbook.
            If Not IsError(var) Then
               bln = True
               Exit For
            End If
         Next iSheet
      End If

      'If you do not find a matching value, do nothing, if you do find a matching value, clear the contents of the cell
      If bln = True Then
         ActiveSheet.Rows(iRow).EntireRow.Delete
      End If
   Next iRow
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
```

End Sub

Comment: I guess the actual data has a last name to identify spouses? Either way, may I suggest you research some more?

Comment: How large are we talking for the dataset?

Comment: I'm matching the fields by an unique identifier. I used first names for clarity sake. I've tried typing in every iteration of the question I could think of in google and here in Stack Overflow, with some answers that are close, but don't quite meet the mark.

Comment: Over 6000 rows in the dataset

Comment: `some answers that are close, but don't quite meet the mark` uhh so modify the close ones to fit your needs instead of simply asking SO to code for you.

Comment: or at least show the work you done so far to try to do what you want and where it's not working :) ...  You also might want to consider a non-vba solution using `Conditional Formatting` ... lots of useful possibilities there without having to code anything :)

Comment: Read your question, how would anybody but you, know that Mike & Kim are married?

Comment: @Davesexcel read the comments - "I'm matching the fields by an unique identifier. I used first names for clarity sake."

Comment: Yep, but are you able you show that in your question?

Comment: Maybe to be a little clearer, this is a military organization where spouses sometimes have different last names. We are trying to identify how well we do with respect to ensuring spouses who are both in the military are stationed in the same area. I have a location identifier and a unique number for each person. I have already used a countif function to identify at least if there is a duplicate somewhere, but trying to match the two is where I'm running into a roadblock. I think I need to use a Do Loop or a For Each function to cycle through the rows.

Comment: I've also tried using that same countif function as my conditional statement using a Do Loop, but it doesn't delete the row (or even just clearing the cell contents). I was using Application.WorksheetFunction.CountIf(ActiveSheet.Range("A:A"), ActiveSheet.Range("I" & currentRow)) > 0. Current row starts at 2 and then adds 1 for each iteration of the loop. The function works within excel to give me a true or false.

Comment: post your code that you have tried, I think you are missing the point,  you say you tried but we see nothing so it looks to us as if you just want us to do it for you.

Comment: @Sorceri Got it. I'm running my latest attempt now and will post once it's complete. New to the board, so I apologize for my ignorance.

Comment: @Sorceri edited my response to include code. Only problem is that it ends up clearing the contents for both people instead of just the one. Found the example on the msdn site

Comment: Appreciate the helpful feedback. Figured it out with a variation of the code that I previously posted. It didn't originally work because I didn't delete the entire row (thus the "Spouse" column data still existed, so it saw the same data twice). By deleting the entire row, I eliminated that possibility. I'm sorry for my original ignorance, and will ensure the full extent of my efforts is posted up front to avoid confusion. I have edited the code in the post for anyone's future efforts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put this formula in C1 (Assuming your data starts in A1 and B1) `=COUNTIFS(A$1:A1,B1,B$1:B1,A1)`

Drag down

Filter data to remove none 0

It works using an expanding range, counting the occurrence of the flip. An expanding range is used to stop it from counting the original ie the one you want to keep.

Here is my sample data and results:

```
Kim     Mike    0
Bob     Mary    0
Jim     Susan   0
Mary    Bob     1
Dave    Angela  0
Mike    Kim     1
```

Comment: Liked yours better, deleted mine.

Comment: I wouldn't delete mate, SO is a great working think tank and alternative methods are always useful, it shows the steps people can take to get to the same answer and sometimes shows functions that may not have been considered before. Different or longer doesn't mean wrong, it just means different :)

Comment: I used a COUNTIF to find the duplicates, but couldn't figure out how to only mark the second occurrence as a duplicate. Thanks!

Comment: Another great aspect to this is the ability to keep all of the original data and just using a filter. This is perfect.

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to change this to suit your needs. It compares columns A & B to look for duplicates and if found, deletes them. It's code I previously wrote for something else but you're welcome to see if it works for you.

```
Sub FindDuplicates()

Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim numberOfAccounts As Long, numberOfBillClasses As Long
Dim nxtRow As Long
Dim checkForRange As Range, DupeRange As Range

numberOfAccounts = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
esrd = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1

For i = 2 To numberOfAccounts
    Set checkForRange = Range("B" & i)

    For j = 1 To esrd - 1
        Set DupeRange = Range("A" & j)

        If StrComp(CStr(checkForRange.Value), CStr(DupeRange.Value), vbTextCompare) = 0 Then
            checkForRange.Interior.ColorIndex = 22
        End If
        Set DupeRange = Nothing
    Next j
    Set checkForRange = Nothing
Next i
End Sub

'This macro will delete the duplicates found after using the above macro.

Sub DeleteDuplicates()
    Dim Lastrow As Long
    Dim Lrow As Long
    Dim CalcMode As Long
    Dim ViewMode As Long

    With Application
        CalcMode = .Calculation
        .Calculation = xlCalculationManual
        .ScreenUpdating = False
    End With

    Lastrow = Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        For Lrow = Lastrow To 2 Step -1
                    If Cells(Lrow, "B").Interior.ColorIndex = 22 Then
                        Cells(Lrow, "B").Delete
                    End If
        Next Lrow

'Removes color from duplicate cells
     Columns("B:B").Select
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlNone
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use this formula:

```
=IFERROR(IF(AND(SUM(($A:$A&$B:$B=A1&B1)+($B:$B&$A:$A=A1&B1))>1,ROW(INDEX($B:$B,MATCH(A1,$B:$B,0)))<ROW()),"Duplicate",""),"")
```

In an empty column, like column C put it in C1, confirm with Ctrl-Shift-Enter.  Then Copy down.  I t will put "Duplicate" in the second version of any matches it finds.

Then sort on column C to bring "Duplicate" to the top and delete all those rows.

Comment: Probably much more elegant than my method (the method I used with the Match function worked great, but took a good while to run)